# Negotiating the number of articles during PhD

Tags: publications, phd, advisor, negotiation

I have contacted a professor at a prestigious university. They mention they'd be glad to have me as a PhD student, if some funding gets approved.

However, to complete the PhD program I am expected by them to publish three times in good journals. This to me seems quite a lot, possibly meaning staying in the PhD program for well over the canonical 4 years, say, 5 or 6. There is no departmental rule on this.

Is it commonplace and advisable to negotiate the number of publications to e.g. 2 good journal papers? If so, do you have any tips on how to achieve this?

I expect the answer to be quite negative, also because at such university there will surely be another candidate willing to take my place and commit to 3 journal publications. Don't get me wrong, I am very enthusiastic about starting my doctorate but I need also to look at the medium term and to avoid dropping out because of too much pressure.

---

I am in Switzerland and in a STEM field.

Comment: These things aren't typically negotiable, especially not ahead of time, but they are really, really stupid policies. They encourage publishing in predatory journals, fabricating results, and salami slicing, and leave your graduation timeline up to editors and reviewers who cannot be expected to prioritize your graduation. Rather than negotiation, you could ask whether there is any typical flexibility in this rule (e.g., submitted papers count or some papers can 'count' for 2), and if not go somewhere else that has spent effort thinking about students and the implications of their policies.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike Except that I would need to publish in good journals, not predatory ones :-)

Thank you for your comment

Comment: There isn't necessarily a red line between them, and it's common that journals once considered reputable are eventually seen as less than.

Comment: You'll also see questions posted here by students dealing with the problem that their advisor wants them to publish their paper in Science and is willing to wait years passing the paper among journals of gradually decreasing stature, trying to get a high-profile paper for themselves, while their student just needs the paper to be *published somewhere* to graduate. A reasonable graduate program would see that the work already done to get something publishable is worth allowing graduation, let the thesis committee judge quality, and let the publishing process take place on its own timeline.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike I would interpret "good" to be a lot stronger than merely "not predatory".

Comment: @EspeciallyLime There isn't a lot of room to maneuver there. The most sought after journals expect work to be somehow "impactful", often conditional on particular results; it's not fair to expect a graduate student must get the "right kind" of results those journals expect rather than merely perform solid work. The next tier of journals may typically practice good peer review practices, yet are also under pressure by their publisher to collect fees from authors. It's not always possible to know where those fall and not everyone agrees about which cross the line.

Comment: While asking the students to publish X papers in journals does not seem the best approach to me for a supervisor (one big impactful paper can take longer and be worth more than 3 papers in top journals), your question basically boils down to "How can I do less than my supervisor expects for my PhD".

Comment: You write "I'm expected to...". I advise to try to find out in the first place what exactly the (written) rules are. It won't hurt you asking "what happens if I don't manage to do that". Also find out how a PhD thesis is ultimately assessed. If this is a fixed and set in stone rule, there is no way to negotiate, but you should try to know as precisely as possible what the rule actually is and how things work. Maybe it's just a recommendation and people quite regularly get away without doing that? (I've seen things communicated as "expectation" that were never enforced.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have some evidence that this professor treats others differently, you probably have no basis for complaint. In those fields in which a "dissertation" is a set of published papers, three seems to be about the right number to expect.

Even asking might have negative consequences. What do you have to offer in a "negotiation"?

If you are in the third or fourth year of such a program and the third publication isn't imminent, then you might be able to talk about it with the professor, but it seems unlikely you will find success initially if this is their established standard, never mind the lack of department rules.

I suspect that if you look elsewhere you will probably find the same thing, and even if you are allowed to "get by" with only two it is impossible to predict how it will go in advance of starting the research.

The flip side, of course, is that high standards will actually benefit your career if you meet them.

Answer (score 1):

*Is it commonplace and advisable to negotiate the number of publications to e.g. 2 good journal papers? If so, do you have any tips on how to achieve this?*

I've never heard of anyone negotiating beforehand. However, it might be worth checking with current students if this is a hard graduation requirement or a guideline. In my department, incoming students are also told that they will need 3 papers. The actual number that graduating students have seems to vary from zero to 6+, depending on the situation and subfield. That being said, if even it if it isn't a hard requirement, it sounds like you'd still be expected to put in an amount of work that should suffice to produce 3 good publications. (Which seems appropriate for a 4 year PhD after a Masters').